# Changing CSS properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a gradual blur transition in an html image using JS. I'm using an initial style , then updating the style property using document object and a global variable.

But the following code doesn't update anything:

```js
var val = 8

function adjust_blur() {
  document.getElementById("image").style.filter = blur(String(val) + "px")
  val -= 1;
}

function update_blur() {
  window.setTimeout(adjust_blur, 1000)
}
```

```css
#image {
  filter: blur(1px);
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/modern-yellow-bitcoin-design_1017-9631.jpg' id='image'>
```

Comment: Any reason why you're doing that with JS rather than CSS?

Comment: Any property for blur transition in CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that

```
.filter = blur(String(val) + "px")
```

is (unintuitively) referring to `window.blur`, which accepts no arguments, but doesn't throw an error when called like that. This results in the browser trying to blur the window, and in `undefined` being assigned to the `.filter` property of the style, which doesn't change the visual appearance at all.

You need to assign a *string* containing `blur(` to the `.filter` property, instead of calling `window.blur`:

```
document.getElementById("image").style.filter = `blur(${String(val) + "px"})`
```

Live demo:

```js
var val = 8

function update_blur() {
  window.setTimeout(adjust_blur, 2000)
}

function adjust_blur() {
  document.getElementById("image").style.filter = `blur(${String(val) + "px"})`
  val -= 1;
}
update_blur()
```

```css
#image {
  filter: blur(1px);
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/modern-yellow-bitcoin-design_1017-9631.jpg' id='image'>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you mean correctly, you may want to use `setInterval` function instead of `setTimeout`

```js
    var val = 8

    function update_blur() {
        window.setInterval(adjust_blur, 1000)
    }

    function adjust_blur() {
        document.getElementById("image").style.filter = "blur(" + String(val) + "px)"
        val -= 1;
    }
    update_blur()
```

```css
    #image {
        filter: blur(1px);
        max-width: 600px;
    }
```

```html
<body onload="update_blur()">
    <img src='https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/modern-yellow-bitcoin-design_1017-9631.jpg' id='image'>
```